# Let $M$ be the set of all $2\times2$ matrices with real entries and let $f: M \mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be the determinant map is bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be the set of all $2\times2$ matrices with real entries and let $f: M \mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be the determinant map is bijective?

Comment: Are there two matrices with the same determinant?

Comment: yes, obviously, there are two different matrices, still the determinant is the same, for example, matrix I_2 and matrix -I_2.

Comment: @RezaHabibi I believe this was a rhetorical question....

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* What are $\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$?